# Macbook Pro doesn't react to any key combinaton at start up

Tags: macbook-pro, recovery

I have a Macbook pro 2009. I had to do a hard reset on it. I was at the installing stage, when it just shut down itself, and now, when I turn it on, only the folder with the question mark is flashing.
But my problem is that, I cannot go back to recovery mode, or any other mode. When I shutdown, and turn it back (while pressing the right key combinations) and just gets to the flashing folder again.
Maybe I dont shut it down correcty? It doesnt even show the loading bar. Just a white screen, then the folder.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: It could be a hardware issue.  Try plugging in an external keyboard and trying the key combinations you tried earlier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255423/hard-drive-is-not-showing-up-on-my-mac-laptop

Comment: The only key combinations that should work on startup are holding down option or "c" to alter the boot sequence. (See my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when there is no information on any hard drive that the computer can process. This means that at some point you likely accidentally deleted the recovery partition of your hard drive. There is no regular recovery partition so the computer has no idea what to do.

You need to have a bootable USB drive to do anything with that computer besides use it as a very expensive paperweight. Find a USB drive and someone with a Mac and make yourself an OS X (or MacOS) install disk. Then boot from that drive (by holding down Option during boot). Then wipe your internal drive and install the OS (which will automatically install a recovery partition).